# SQL sorted by a diferent fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next tables and rows. And I need to write a SELECT that returns all categories sorted by:

(A) the number of items they have
and (B) the category name.

This query should fetch the following columns: the category name, the number of items (AS N_ITEMS) and the average price of the titles in that category (AS AVERAGE_PRICE)

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `CATEGORY_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CATEGORY_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `category` (`CATEGORY_ID`, `CATEGORY_NAME`) VALUES
(1, 'Sports'),
(2, 'Actualités'),
(3, 'Animaux'),
(4, 'Economie'),
(5, 'Cuisine');


CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `ITEM_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CATEGORY_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ITEM_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ITEM_PRICE` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `item` (`ITEM_ID`, `CATEGORY_ID`, `ITEM_NAME`, `ITEM_PRICE`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Equip', '6.00'),
(2, 2, 'Le Monde', '3.00'),
(3, 2, 'Le Parisien', '2.50'),
(4, 2, 'France soir', '3.00'),
(5, 3, '30 Million damis', '6.20'),
(6, 3, 'Cheval pratique', '4.50'),
(7, 4, 'Capital', '2.50');

ALTER TABLE `category`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`CATEGORY_ID`);

ALTER TABLE `item`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ITEM_ID`);

ALTER TABLE `category`
  MODIFY `CATEGORY_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `item`
  MODIFY `ITEM_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select CATEGORY_NAME, count(ITEM_ID) as noofItem,avg(item_price) as avgprice
from category inner join item on category.category_id=item.category_id
group by CATEGORY_NAME
order by noofItem,CATEGORY_NAME
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot